# AutoMapper - Map to a two dimensional array of different types

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, automapper

I have a class which has a list of measurements like this:

```cs
public class MeasurementChartXY
{
    public DateTime X { get; set; }
    public double? Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use AutoMapper to map this to a 2-dimensional array (or something else?).
The first part of the array should be the result of the JavaScript `.getTime()` method which returns the number of milliseconds after 1970 and the second contains the value.

So the result should look something like this:

```
[[1688975454487, 3.45],[1688975454587, 3.46],[1688975454687, 3.45]]
```

I tried some stuff, but I can't seem to find a good solution so far.

Thought this would be easy.

Kind regards

Comment: Without AutoMapper, you can also achieve converting from the List of MeasurementChartXY to nested array with double type via LINQ. But it seems your array is with `long` and `double` value.

Comment: Yeah true. I tried a dictionary but this didn't work on my part.

Comment: A nested list of object / dynamic type should allow you to store values with different types. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1tawoc)

Comment: I just tested your solution and this works! Thanks man! I expected this would give me a boost in response speed, but this is relatively small. Anyway... Thx!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, you can achieve converting the `List<MeasurementChartXY>` value to nested array with *System.Linq* without the *AutoMapper*.

To store the values with different types in the array, you can use `object`/`dynamic` type.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<List<object>> result = input.Select(x => new List<object> { ConvertToTimestamp(x.X), x.Y.GetValueOrDefault() })
    .ToList();
```

```cs
private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    return (long)((TimeSpan)(value - Epoch)).TotalSeconds;
}
```